# Can I exclude a word?

Tags: word-choice

Can I say "I began my career a medical secretary" instead of "I began my career as a medical secretary"? (Exclude the word "as")

Comment: Is that the entire sentence? For example, it *could* work in "I began my career a medical secretary, but I ended as a Consultant in brain surgery," (although I think that sounds best with at least one *as*).

Comment: It's a little unusual for business communication, but I don't think it would be remarkable in literature. It's not so different from *I was trained a spy* and *I am born a healer*, or even *She raised me a Southern gentleman*.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, the sentence

> I began my career as a medical secretary.

ends somewhat abruptly—as though the author forgot to complete it with some crucial detail such as "in a small hospital in Duluth." That's because "medical secretary" can be understood as a career, and not merely as a first position in a varied employment history. In this respect, however, dropping the "as" from the sentence doesn't dispel potential confusion over whether you are talking about your lifelong career as a medical secretary or about your more varied professional career in which "medical secretary" was the first of a number of different positions you've held.

So my first suggestion would be to change "career" to "working life" (if some of the jobs you've held are in the general area of medicine and others are not) or to "career in the medical profession" (if all of the jobs you've held are in that area). That is,

> I began my working life as a medical secretary.

or

> I began my career in the medical profession as a medical secretary.

With regard to the more general questions of whether and when you should consider retaining or omitting "as" in a sentence like "I began my career as X," it seems to me that retaining the "as" is more important when X refers to the career itself and less important when X refers to something independent of the career. For example, you might say

> I began my career a wide-eyed innocent.

and many readers would scarcely notice the absence of "as." That's because "wide-eyed innocent" isn't a career, so the phrase "a wide-eyed innocent" doesn't explain the word "career" but rather associates it with a different subject altogether—the speaker's naivete at the time that he or she began working. In fact, one might argue that saying

> I began my career as a wide-eyed innocent.

is slightly distracting because it momentarily invites the interpretation that "wide-eyed innocent" is a career. The reader will reject that misreading almost instantly, but avoiding even trivial and very brief misinterpretations is part of writing effectively and (from the reader's perspective) pleasantly. Omitting "as" in this instance doesn't have any disadvantage that I can see.

Comment: _In 2010 I began my career as a medical secretary._ doesn't seem to end abruptly.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree. But I suspect that the lack of abruptness is owing to the introductory words "In 2010," which make the sentence equivalent to saying " I began my career as a medical secretary in 2010." My reading of the sentence in that case is that "medical secretary" is a career that the author has pursued since 2010, and the phrase "in 2010" fills the vacancy in specificity that in my answer I filled with "in a small hospital in Duluth."

Comment: What's really going on is that these sentences are grammatically ambiguous. _as an X_ can either modify _began_ or _career_. But context and common sense disambiguates many of them. OTOH, without _as_, it always modifies _began_.

Answer (score -1):

You can, but it would sound strange. Especially in writing.